# jQuery: Making a Favorite button with function?

Tags: jquery

Right now i made this:

```
<a href="#" title="[+] Add as favorite"><div class="addFavorite"></div></a>
```

the class="addFavorite", is a normal grey star.

Then i have another class="AlreadyFavorite", that is a yellow star.

I want to make a function, so when you click on the grey star, it sends an ajax call(?) and then  on success it turns yellow(changing class to AlreadyFavorite).

I know how to make a onclick function that send a ajax call, but how do i change the style/change the image icon to yellow?

CSS:

```
.addFavorit{
 background: url('../images/addFavorit.png');
 width: 48px;
 height: 48px;

}
.alreadyFavorit{
 background: url('../images/addFavorit_hover.png');
 width: 48px;
 height: 48px;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try not to repeat yourself where possible and avoid unneeded elements:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="fav" title="[+] Add as favorite">&nbsp;</a>
```

CSS:

```
a#fav{
 background: url('../images/addFavorit.png');
 display: block;
 width: 48px;
 height: 48px;

}

a#fav.active{
 background: url('../images/addFavorit_hover.png');
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function addFav(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/favorites/add",
      data: {"id": articleID},
      success: function(){
           $('a#fav')
                 .addClass('active')
                 .attr('title','[-] Remove from favorites')
                 .unbind('click')
                 .bind('click', removeFav)
           ;
      }
    });
}

function removeFav(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/favorites/remove",
      data: {"id": articleID},
      success: function(){
            $('a#fav')
                 .removeClass('active')
                 .attr('title','[+] Add as favorite')
                 .unbind('click')
                 .bind('click', addFav)
            ;
      }
    });
}

//this will make the link listen to function addFav (you might know this already)
$('a#fav').bind('click', addFav);
```

Clicking the link the first time the url specified in `addFav()` will be called and after successful processing the function defined in success will be called. The result:

```
<a href="#" id="fav" class="active" title="[-] Remove as favorite">&nbsp;</a>
```

The second click will call `removeFav()` due to the rebinding. The result will be:

```
<a href="#" id="fav" class="" title="[+] Add as favorite">&nbsp;</a>
```

After that it's an endless loop given your server doesn't act out.

Comment: Works great. How do i remove the class again if you click again?

Comment: Added the removal. Please mark the answer as correct if it works for you ;-)

Comment: Hi, yes i will but where should i add the removeclass, so it removes when you click second time.. so you can when you click:addClass clickagain: removeClass, clickagain:addClass... get me?

Comment: @Karem I rewrote my whole post and hope it's much clearer now.

Comment: Hello i get an error from jquery´s library when i use $('a#fav').bind('click','addFav'); ? Is it because i have putted it inside document.ready? but if i dont, then nothing happens either?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the class to `alreadyFavorite` after the ajax call? or is there something I am missing?

or is it `alreadyFavorit` (as in the CSS)

```
$('div').removeClass('addFavorit').addClass('alreadyFavorit')
```