# unbinding and binding help with user defined function

Tags: jquery, function, event-handling, click, bind

I'm trying to have a button change image when clicking and then change back when user clicks again. I saw an example on binding and unbinding on stackoverflow ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626350/jquery-making-a-favorite-button-with-function)) but I was messing around with the function and it seems like I can't do

```
$('a#fav').bind('click','addFav');
```

The code snippet above won't run an event on click, but if I do something like this

```
    $('a#fav').bind('click',function(){
    alert('test');
});
```

It will work. Can someone help me get a user defined function to work with .bind and .unbind like how it is in the example?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use strings for the function reference and it will work:

```
function addFav(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('called');
    return false;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a#fav').bind('click', addFav);
})
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/BpGXD/

Here's an example with unbind: http://jsfiddle.net/BpGXD/2/

Comment: I got my bind to work where it will change , but it won't change back when I click it again. Maybe it has to do something with this? Can I unbind it and then bind it like this? Thanks! `$('a#favorites').removeClass('active').text('title','Remove favorites').unbind('click').bind('click',removeFav)`

Answer (score 0):

`bind` takes a function reference as second argument. What you have passed in your example is a string so it is not going to work. You can define function and then just pass the function name or you can also directly pass anonymous function as second argument which will be executed when the event triggers

```
function addFav(){
   alert("click fired");
}

$('a#fav').bind('click', addFav);

//Or

$('a#fav').bind('click', function(){
   alert("click fired");
});
```