# jQuery not removing "class" attribute name when using removeClass()

Tags: jquery

I've written a "Favourite" feature (special almost entirely to Stefan Hoth and his reply to a previous [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626350/jquery-making-a-favorite-button-with-function)), which is — for the most part — working. However, it's quirky.

Firstly, after visting a page, the favourite button needs pressing twice before it begins to work, after which it works with a single click to switch between states.

Secondly, the removeClass() method only appears happy to remove the "active" part of the class="active" attribute, which is weird.

```
function favouriteAdd (){
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "bookmarks/jq_set_bookmark_as_favourite/add/" + $("a#favourite").data("bookmark"),
        success: function () {
            $('a#favourite')
            .addClass('active')
            .attr('title', "Remove as Favorite")
            .unbind('click')
            .bind('click', favouriteRemove);
        }
    });
}

function favouriteRemove (){
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "bookmarks/jq_set_bookmark_as_favourite/remove/" + $("a#favourite").data("bookmark"),
        success: function () {
            $('a#favourite')
            .removeClass('active')
            .attr('title', "Add as Favorite")
            .unbind('click')
            .bind('click', favouriteAdd);
        }
    });
}

if($('a#favourite').hasClass('active') == true) {
    $('a#favourite').bind('click', favouriteRemove);
} else {
    $('a#favourite').bind('click', favouriteAdd);
}
```

I'm guessing the solution is elementary for the initiated, but I'm sadly at in the elementary class when it comes to jQuery.

Comment: have you checked that id is unique on page?

Comment: I would move the active IF test into ONE handler and not do the unbind/rebind in your success handler. That can sometimes cause headaches and this way you only ever have one handler you don't have to constantly rebind. To clarify, I would make a favoriteClick function as a handler that does the test and calls the appropriate ajax based on that. I don't know if that would solve your problem but hope it helps.

Comment: Hi guys, Stefan V nailed it. Also, I had the if() statement jumbled up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this but be careful as this will erase the entire class attribute and if you have additional classes in there they will be wiped:

```
$('a#favourite').removeAttr("class");
```

Also, try putting your if statement in an [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) function

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
   // code here
 });
```